# Java 8 stream convert a Set to single value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following stream which returns a `Map<String, List<Set<String>>>`:

```
Map<String, List<Set<String>>> collect = conditions.stream().collect(groupingBy(Condition::getKey, mapping(Condition::getValues, toList())));
```

My object Condition have the following attributes:

```
String key;
List<String> values;
```

How can I convert this return into a `Map<String, List<String>>` excluding the duplicates and keep the same key?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck trying to convert this set into a single value as I informed in the desirable return.

Comment: so in short you have a `key` mapped to a `List<Set<String>>` and all you want to ensure is the conversion of `List<String>` ...something like         `List<Set<String>> some;
        List<String> res = some.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(toList());` maybe just for the values of your Map ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to proceed with `groupingBy` then you'd do:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result =  conditions.stream()
              .collect(groupingBy(Condition::getKey, mapping(Condition::getValues, toList())))
              .entrySet().stream()
              .collect(toMap(f -> f.getKey(), f -> f.getValue().stream()
                       .flatMap(List::stream).distinct().collect(toList())));
```

but this may be more compact with `toMap` with a merge function:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> result = conditions.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Condition::getKey, f -> new HashSet<>(f.getValues()), 
                    (l, r) -> {l.addAll(r);return l;}));
```

Comment: The doubt I had was, what does excluding the duplicates mean here? Can you explain that part in your answer?

Comment: Hi nullpointer, in my entity I can have duplicate strings in values.

Comment: @Nogueira then where are you trying to remove the duplicates from? I mean assuming `conditions` is a `List<Condition>` , isn't it?

Comment: just realized my previous comment might sound a little bit confusing (hence removed), so here's another try --> "The doubt I had was, what does excluding the duplicates mean here?", so first we group then apply mapping yielding `Map<String, List<List<String>>>` then what the OP wants is for each of the  `List<List<String>>` to be converted to a `List<String>` where this list only contains the "distinct" elements.  The grouping is still required as we need all the `List<String>` of each `Condition`'s grouping adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Java 9+, you can use [`Collectors.flatMapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> collect = conditions.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Condition::getKey, collectingAndThen(flatMapping(
                condition -> condition.getValues().stream(), toSet()
        ), ArrayList::new)));
```

Because you want to filter out duplicates, it first collects to a `Set`, and then dumps it to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Can we simplify it to: `Map<String, List<String>> collect = conditions.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Condition::getKey, flatMapping(condition -> condition.getValues().stream().distinct(), toList())));`?  Using `distinct` would prevent creating the intermediate `Set`.

Comment: @LuCio This wouldn't work. You're calling `distinct` on the result of `Condition.getValues()` which already returns a `Set` (so no duplicates). The point here is to find duplicate values between two conditions which have the same key (e.g. if `condition1.getKey().equals(condition2.getKey())` then some of `condition1.getValues()` can duplicate `condition2.getValues()`).

Comment: You're right. I missed that OP's `collect` is a `Map` whose values are of  type `List` of `Set`. Calling `distinct` on a `Stream` backed by a `Set` makes no sense.